# Image output and tagging

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) and [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) tags. There doesn't seem to be any tag which is unambiguously for challenges which involve output in an image file format, so they sometimes get put in [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) and sometimes ([e.g.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/generate-newton-fractals)) don't get any tag. Moreover, some challenges which ask for ASCII-art output (e.g. [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/implement-a-graphing-calculator), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/illuminate-a-mirrored-room)) are tagged as [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) but not [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art).

Inconsistent usage is obviously a small problem, which can be fixed by agreeing a standard and then editing tags as appropriate. But I think it's also a problem that tag completion from "image" doesn't send you to "graphical-output".

I am tempted to create an [image](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) tag and retag everything in [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) as either [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) or [image](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image), or both where the question gives the implementer a choice between the two ([e.g.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/generate-the-stack-overflow-logo)). However, the name doesn't strike me as adequate, because there have been questions which take images as input but don't produce them as output.

Maybe it's sufficient to make [image](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) a synonym for [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) for the time being and to change that later if there's much call for it to cover graphical input too.

Suggestions?

Comment: I'd have thought that the distinction was clear with the tags we have, but I don't have any strong objections to this plan.

Comment: @dmckee, I missed one point that I wanted to make. Will edit.

Comment: What about challenges involving image _input_ (like [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/code-39-barcode-scanner))?  How should they be tagged?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, I raise that question myself in paragraph 3.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's a concrete proposal: I suggest we create [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) for challenges that have images as input and [image-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-output) for challenges that (only) ask for them as output.  Make [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) a synonym for [image-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-output), *or* vice versa.  (I have no great preference either way, but IMO [image-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-output) should exist *at least* as a synonym, so that users typing in "image" can find it.)  Questions that only ask for ASCII art output should be retagged as [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) (and not as [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)).

Comment: It's been two months and nobody seems opposed to this (and there's even one support vote, yay!), so I'm planning to start implementing this. The first step will be to retag questions with ASCII art output as [tag:ascii-art].